# Media Query font-size being applied to ALL settings instead of just the targeted setting

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to have my title appear in-line for a widget on all mobile devices.
My regular css is:

```
.mobile_1.vertical-strip-layout .widget-header {
  font-family: "Barlow Semi Condensed", "Khand", "Nunito", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

However, on an iPhone 5/SE screen the text gets smushed together. To avoid this, I used a media query to adjust the font-size accordingly:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .mobile_1.vertical-strip-layout .widget-header{
    font-size: 14.5px;
  }
}
```

This works great, however instead of this `font-size: 14.5;` **only** being applied to an iPhone 5/SE (ie a screen size with a max-width of 568px) it's being applied to **all** screen sizes.

How can I set this media query to take effect **JUST** for an iPhone 5/SE (max-width: 568px) setting?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the unit definition on the 3rd line:

Instead of:

```
font-size: 18;
```

Use:

```
font-size: 18px;
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add 18px to the example above but tried it with it 18px and that wasn't it (Edited into the question too as well)

Comment: I've built this pen, seems to be working fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyjBxV